# Subscriber receiving but not publishing messages to other subscriber

Tags: winforms, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, nservicebus

We are having a handler web application and two windows application. We have configured the nService Bus to publish the message between these applications all are running on the same machine.

The problem is we are able to publish the message between web to window app1. At this moment window app1 is treated as subscriber and its receiving the message properly. Now we want window app1 to work as publisher and send message to window app2 and then window app2 (as subscriber) then again window app2 to as publisher and send message to window app1.

Web App(Handler App) config section for NService Bus

```
 <configSections>
 <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="Logging" type="NServiceBus.Config.Logging, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
</configSections>

<MsmqTransportConfig   InputQueue="IndustrialCommsEngineQueue"
ErrorQueue="IndustrialErrorQueue"   NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"   MaxRetries="5"/>
<MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="CommsSubscriptionQueue" />
```

Global Asax File for above web app

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
                                     .DefaultBuilder()
                                      .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                                     .XmlSerializer()
                                     .MsmqTransport()
                                         .IsTransactional(true)
                                     .UnicastBus()
                                     .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                                     .CreateBus()
                                     .Start();

    }
```

Window App1 receiving the message through NService bus from web app now we want this to be treated as publisher to publish the NService Bus to send the message to window app2 but its not working.

Config Section for the same

```
<configSections>
<section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
<section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="Logging" type="NServiceBus.Config.Logging, NServiceBus.Core" />
<section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
```

```
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="IndustrialBREQueue" ErrorQueue="IndustrialErrorQueue" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>   
<MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="BRESubscriptionQueue1"/>
<Logging Threshold="WARN"/>
<UnicastBusConfig>
<MessageEndpointMappings>
  <add Messages="ComEventMessage" Endpoint="IndustrialCommsEngineQueue"/>
<add Messages="AlarmEventMessage" Endpoint="IndustrialAlarmEngineQueue"/>
    </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Publishing code in window app1 fires on click of a button code is as follows

```
 IBus bus =NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .Log4Net()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .UnicastBus()
            .LoadMessageHandlers()
            .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

Window app2 needs to receive the message from window app1 which is not working more over we also want window aap2 to be work as publisher to publish the NService Bus and sends back some data to window app1 after processing the data this process is breaking.

Config Section for the Window app2

```
<configSections>
<section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="Logging" type="NServiceBus.Config.Logging, NServiceBus.Core"/>
<section name="MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig"  type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core"/>
</configSections>
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="IndustrialAlarmEngineQueue"  ErrorQueue="IndustrialErrorQueue"    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"    MaxRetries="5"/>
```

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
<MessageEndpointMappings><add Messages="BREEventMessage" Endpoint="IndustrialBREQueue"/> </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

publishing code in window app2

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        IBus bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                   .Log4Net()
                  .DefaultBuilder()
                  .XmlSerializer()
                  .MsmqTransport()
                  .IsTransactional(true)
                  .UnicastBus()
                  .LoadMessageHandlers()
                  .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
                  .CreateBus()
                  .Start();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FormAlarmsEngine());
    }
```

Earlier this process was working but some how stoped not being to figure out what we are missing now. What we have done we have just restarted the server where these apps are placed after that stoped b to c and c to b connection. More over we are not getting the message queues for b to c process. The process we want is A to b , b to c and c to b.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to publish or can you just use point to point communication?

Comment: Thanks for your time Adam. Yes I really need to publish.

Comment: First I would recommend bootstrapping as you did with windows app 2 across the board.  If everyone is to be a Publisher and Subscriber, then you will have to map all message assemblies except your own in each windows app.

Comment: Hi Adam, apart from above I would like share another demo app which I have created on my local machine to test the process and it is working fine at my local end I mean A-b,B-C and C-B. But as soon as I run the app on the server machine it stooped the first process  which A-B rest process is working. B is not receiving the message from A on the server. I will be attaching the code and the MSMQ Screen shot more clearance.Following are the links, [link](http://speedy.sh/DwBPQ/WorkingAtobtoctob.rar),[link](http://speedy.sh/HJdTK/msmqscreenshot.jpg). Please have a look.

Comment: Hello Adam are you there.?

Comment: We have solved the issue at our own end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above has been fixed long back by defining proper `<MessageEndpointMappings>` in web config and using Bus.Send instead of using Bus.Publish. By this it worked for me.